# Ubuntu 20 installer shows 0 free space and no partitions. How can I fix it?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, disk

I have Windows 10 installed on SSD 256GB,and I have 1TB HDD and I have 200GB unallocated. My HDD disk is Basic and MBR and my SSD is GPT, and I want to install Ubuntu on the unallocated space but I can't see it in the Ubuntu installer.
BIOS is set to AHCI.

Windows Disk partitions:

[image: Windows Disk partitions]

Ubuntu Installer:

[image: Ubuntu Installer]

Answer (score 0):

The `free space = 0` at the end there is not what's available.. this is space which does not belong to a partition at the moment at the end of your disk..

What I would do, is boot from the Ubuntu USB, start gparted, and create a partition out of this unallocated space (200Gb), make a note of how it's then named e.g.:`/dev/sdX` and then in the Installer use that as my `/` partition where I would put the Linux installation.